# Import a range of data from a different sheet given a criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am new to google sheets and xcel. I have two sheets, one, named "Oil", with a product listing, with a relative bar code #. I am looking to find that bar code number (located in "Oil" in cell B3, and subsequently B4, B5, etc.) on a second sheet named "Results", in column A, and return the values in "Results" from column D to column M.

Basically wanting to copy lab results from "Results", located from column D to column M, over to "Oil" for the specific product, searching by bar code number. The tranferred results will be in the same D to M cell range.

Comment: If you don't get it working the way you need, please make a copy of your sheet, swap in believable dummy data over anything sensitive, and Share it so Anyone With The Link can Edit.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) to check the Oil barcode against the column in Results, and then pull in the desired columns from the matching row. [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) can auto-fill new Oil rows as they are entered. You can use an IF to check if a row's B is still empty, and leave D:M blank too if so.

Set Oil's cell D3 to something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(LEN($B3:$B)),"",VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT($B3:$B), Results!$A$2:$M, {4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}, FALSE)))
```

I edited this formula to work well with your barcodes. Your sheet has some type-mismatching. Since they often contain leading zeros, the most straightforward fix would be to treat them all as plain text. Open your Results sheet, select column A, and from the menus, select: Format, Number, Plain text.

Comment: Hopefully that link will open for you!

Comment: The share was not set so we can make edits, but I was able to make a copy.

Comment: Consider marking your question as solved. Also be sure to read the edit I just added to the end, since you may be missing some bar code matches with them as they are now.